# Is there a fast way to "audition" different textures on a model?

Tags: texturing

[I used this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rzXNZkEoTAk) to achieve some great results in texturing. It's kind of a convoluted mess though and it's taking me *way* longer than I feel like it should.

In a perfect world, I'd just right click a model, and automatically apply textures from a drop down list of photorealistic presets. Does an addon like this exist?

Comment: There's an add-on called Blendermada that's basically what you just discribed. I've never used it so I don't know how good it actually is, but you could certainly give it a try. (Blendermada.com)

Comment: Thank you! This looks like a great resource, I'll definitely try it out.